# Why doesn't $_SESSION work after switching hosts?

Tags: php, session, hosts

Yesterday I switched hosts from [000webhost](http://000webhost.com) to [ipage](http://ipage.com) however when I went to login to my site the session wasn't being written. I have checked and the code is exactly the same on both hosts, why would this make a difference and how would i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in `phpinfo()` if PHP has session support and also check if `session.auto_start` is enabled.

You can also enable it in a *.htaccess* file with:

```
php_flag session.auto_start on
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your new provider doesn't automatically start sessions.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

Try calling session_start(); at the beginning of your script.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a `session_start()` call on the new host which wasn't needed on the old one

Comment: I have session start in my header, so I don't think it's this